# k-modes silhouette and elbow plots

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to clusterize several rows (more than 200.000), each of them with 150 binary attributes. For this, I have run k-modes clustering and now I am trying to generate the silhouette plot and the elbow method in order to know what k-value is probably the most appropiate.

Does anyone know how I can proceed to calculate both taking into account that values are not numerical?. For example, I do not know if the total cost of the process (distance between elements to its centroid measured by simple-matching distance) is similar to the WSS (within cluster sum of squared errors).

Any idea or any illustrative sample code is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Silhouette can be used with any metric.

Use, e.g., Hamming distance or Jaccard.

Comment: but what about the question regarding the total cost vs the within-cluster sum of squared errors?

Comment: Elbow plots rarely work anyway. Silhouette is better, if you can afford to compute it. And you can of course look at the average Hamming distance to the cluster representative, of course, and you'll get your elbow plot.

Comment: I do not know if I totally understand you. Do you mean I can plot a correct elbow plot as a sum of the average hamming distance to each representative cluster, i .e. for k=3, the sum(avg(hamming_distance_i)) where i=1,2,3.... Would this be correct?.

Comment: When is an elbow plot "correct"? It's just a plot of some function f, which you expect to have a certain shape.